# Is there a way to skip empty buckets during bucket sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, bucket

Counting sort is kind of a bucket sort.  Let's assume we're using it like this:

- Let `A` be the array to sort
- Let `k` be the max element
- Let `bucket[]` be an array of buckets
- Let each bucket be a linked list (with a start and end pointer)

Then in pseudocode, counting sort looks like this:

```
Counting-Sort (A[], bucket[], k)

1.  Init bucket[]
2.  for i -> 1 to n
3.        add A[i] to bucket[A[i].key].end
4.  for i -> 1 to k
5.        concatenate bucket[i].start to bucket[0].end
6.        bucket[0].end=bucket[i].end
7.  copy bucket[0] to A
```

**Time Complexity by lines:**

1) I know there is a way (not simple but a way) to init array in O(1)

2,3) O(n)

4,5) O(k)

6) O(n)

This gives us a net runtime of O(k+n), which for k >> n is Ω(n), which is bad for us.  But what if we can change lines 4,5 to somehow skip the empty buckets?  This way we will end up having O(n) no metter what k is.

Does anyone know how to do this?  Or is it impossible?

Comment: Presumably you mean "which for k>>n is Omega(**k**)"?

Comment: nope, Omega n, it is AT LEAST as high as n, CAN BE higher... its even a small omega notation which is stronger

Comment: If k>>n, then O(k+n) -> O(k) (note that I'm mixing Omega/O/etc. loosely here, possibly because I misunderstand your concern).

Comment: O(k) but yet Omega(n) that means the running time is somewhere between c*k to c*n

Comment: I guess I must still misunderstand you.  From the structure of your question, I would have imagined you would be complaining about the dominance of `k` on the runtime (when `k` >> `n`, then asymptotically the runtime is proportional to `k`, not `n`).  But you seem to be worried about `n`.

Comment: what i wish for is to make it run no worse then c*n even when k>>n. it runs in O(n+k) which means O(max(k,n)) but i want it to depend on the input size only, no metter which is higher k or n.

Comment: Ok, then I think we agree, you're trying to avoid the asymptotic behaviour being dominated by `k`.  In which case, templatetypedef's answer sounds reasonable for the case when `k >> n`.

Comment: As a follow-up to my answer, I'm pretty sure you can't eliminate the dependency on k without driving up the dependency on n.  The best known sorting algorithms for general integers have runtimes like O(n log log n) or O(n sqrt(log log n)) and are ferociously complex.  I would assume that if there is a way to eliminate k "for free" that it is either beyond the frontiers of research or provably impossible.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to hold an auxilary BST containing which buckets are actually being used.  Whenever you add something to a bucket, if it's the first entry to be placed there, you would also add that bucket's value to the BST.

When you want to then go concatenate everything, you could then just iterate over the BST in sorted order, concatenating just the buckets you find.

If there are z buckets that actually get used, this takes O(n + z log z).  If the number of buckets is large compared to the number actually used, this could be much faster.

More generally - if you have a way of sorting the z different buckets being used in O(f(z)) time, you can do a bucket sort in O(n + f(z)) time.  Maintain a second array of the buckets you actually use, adding a bucket to the array when it's used for the first time.  Before iterating over the buckets, sort in O(f(z)) time the indices of the buckets in usem then iterate across that array to determine what buckets to visit.  For example, if you used y-Fast trees, you could sort in O(n + z log log z).

Hope this helps!

Comment: This wouldnt help 1 reason is if the Bucket sort dealing with a good distrabution of elements in A, which leads to an Ele or Constant of Eles in a bucket would lead us to O(n/c*logn/c) which is O(nlogn) - rather use QuickSort in this case.

Comment: @Ofek: But you said that n << k.  So this will still be less than O(k).

Comment: in some way you are right, but its actually still is not so helpfull since we dont want to assume too much strict rules on the input i.e the distrabution of the input, the input could be with no 2 equal keys and then what? we get to do the buckets partition for dealing with exactly the same problem again - sorting the very same array

Comment: Can you explain a lil about y-Fast?

Comment: @Ofek Ron- You should probably check out the Wikipedia article for van Emde Boas trees, x-Fast trees, and then y-Fast trees to get a sense for how these structures work.  They're definitely not trivial, but it might be good to know about them if you want to do fast integer sorts.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the bucket array into an associative array, which yields O(*n* log *n*), and I don't believe you can do better than that for sorting (on average).

O(*n*) is impossible in the general case.

Comment: But doesn't the same problem exist for an associative array when the number of bins vastly exceeds the number of elements>

Comment: @Oli: Yes. I've amended my answer to clarify my stance.